# Is it possible to create and reference objects in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a list of urls that I want the net locations.

```
urls = ["http://server1:53000/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=../maps/Weather.wms.map", 
        "http://server2:53000/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=../maps/Weather.wms.map"]
```

I would normally just write something like this:

```
servers = []
for url in urls:
    o = urlparse(url)
    servers.append(o.netloc)
```

Then I immediately thought, "I should just put that into a comprehension" and proceeded to write this (which of course doesn't work):

```
servers = [o.netloc() for urlparse(url) as o in urls]
```

Does python have a way to do this type of complex comprehension?  (perhaps in 3.x?)

On a more academic level, would doing this type of complex comprehension move too far away from being "pythonic"?  It seems relatively intuitive to me, but I've been completely off-base on these things before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to assign to an intermediary name, just access the `.netloc` attribute on the return value of `urlparse()` directly:

```
servers = [urlparse(url).netloc for url in urls]
```

It's a perfectly pythonic thing to do it this way.

Comment: This would be one of those derp moments. I feel like I 'should' know better.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Is this specific case, there is simply no need for the intermediary variable `o`, as your loop could be simplified to this

```
for url in urls:
    servers.append(urlparse(url).netloc)
```

which can then be directly transformed to a list comprehension, as in [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38850776/1639625).

But in the case that you really *need* that variable, e.g. because you want to use it more than once, or want to perform some checks first without performing `urlparse(url)` twice?

```
for url in urls:
    o = urlparse(url)
    if o is not None:
        servers.append((o.netloc, o.protocol))
```

In this case, you can nest a generator expression inside your list comprehension, performing the calculation and declaring the variable to be used in the outer list comprehension:

```
servers = [(o.netloc, o.protocol) for o in (urlparse(url) for url in urls) 
           if o is not None]
```

Comment: I really wish I could mark two answers as accepted since I asked a two-part question. This is indeed what I was originally thinking.